# React Router - Why is my URL Param not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to route from a products page to an individual product page, however my URL param (:productName) isn't working. At present, the view stays on the Products component and just removes the list of products.

When the user selects a product from the products page, the view should switch to the Product component and display the title and product information.

I'd also appreciate any advice on how to structure the products section of my app - I have a number of products that all have different images and content. I'm fairly new to React so any information on how to structure this would be amazing!

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import WaterType from "./components/WaterType";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import Product from "./components/Product";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/waterType" component={WaterType} />
        <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
        <Route path="/products/:productName" component={Product} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Products.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductData from "./data/ProductData";

const Products = ({ location }) => {
  const categorySelected = location.categorySelected;
  const waterType = location.waterType;

  const ProductsResult = ProductData.filter(x => x.categories.includes(categorySelected) && x.waterTypes.includes(waterType));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>Current category: {categorySelected && categorySelected}</p>
      <p>Water Type: {waterType && waterType}</p>

      <div className="products">
          <ul>
            {ProductsResult.map((item, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                <Link
                  to={{
                    pathname: '/products/' + item.slug,
                    name: item.name,
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Product.js

```
import React from "react";

const Product = ({ location }) => {
  const productName = location.name;

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{productName}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: Write the router `/products/:productName` before `/products`

Comment: To elaborate on what Keikai said, the <Switch> component accepts the first match it finds. So, `path=/products` matches for both of these URLs; `/products` and `/products/:productName`. For most routing, you want to list the longer routes before the shorter routes to avoid this exact problem.

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the location? /products/1 - it doesn't matter what you put at the end of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments, list the longer routes before the shorter routes because if not, `path=/products` matches both `/products` and `/products/:productName`. It searches `/products/` first and goes there instead of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Under package.json, change home page from '.' to your site ip address.

E.g.
"homepage": "https://37.130.224.2"